# View not dispaying template ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Doing a tutorial with ionic and I cant seem to render a basic page...just blank.

this is my home template home.html

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-balanced">
<h1 class="title">Elite Schedule</h1>
```

```
<ion-tab title="My Teams" icon="ion-star" ui-sref="home.myteams">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-myteams"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

this is the main index page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html >
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>
<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->
<script src="js/platformOverrides.js"></script>

<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<!-- your app's js -->

<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<base href="/" />
</head>
 <body ng-app="eliteApp">
<ion-ng-view></ion-ng-view>
 </body>
 </html>
```

this is my app.js controller

```
(function () {
"use strict"
    var eiliteApp = angular.module("eliteApp", ["ionic"])//injecting ionic as a dependancy

.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
})

eiliteApp.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$locationProvider", function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");//default url
        $stateProvider.state("home", {
            abstract: true,
            url: "/",
            templateUrl: "app/home/home.html"
        })
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]
);
```

})();

what am I missing?

Comment: Replace the tag `<ion-ng-view></ion-ng-view>` to `<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not specifying a controller anywhere. You can either do it in app.config where you define the route or on your template with ng-controller="controllerName" but if that's all your code, you also haven't created a controller yet. It's not clear what you expect to see.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
<ion-ng-view></ion-ng-view>
```

with

```
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```